# How do I import SASS partials located in another directory?

Tags: sass

This is the structure of my SASS files:

```
(at root-level)
CSS
    mainCSSContainer.scss
    _partial1.scss
    _partial2.scss
    _partialn.scss

ANOTHER_DIR
    CSS
        _partialX.scss

ONE_MORE_DIR
    CSS
        _partialY.scss
etc.
```

mainCSSContainer contents

```
@import (_partial1) ; // working. underscore optional
@import (partial2) ; // working
@import (partialn) ; // working

@import (../ANOTHER_DIR/CSS/partialX) ; // not working --> msg
@import (partialX) ; // not working either -->   msg
```

Thus trying to import a SASS partial located in another directory fails and the returned error message reads 'File to import not found or unreadable'.

How do I make it work?

EDITED

Very likely a matter of configuration (paths to directories to search for).

I am using/setting up Sass through Nebteans 8.1 "CSS Prepocessors" properties panel. Thus I am not sure about how to configure the compiler: I searched with the terminal for a config.rb file to edit but could not find any in the Sass directory; also I tried to specify paths in the relevant Compiler options field in Netbeans like so: --include_path "${mysite}/MENUS/CSS". To no avail. I may create/modify a config file as proposed here:Github Config.rb, but I have no clue as to where the file is/should be located.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```scss
@import "/ANOTHER_DIR/CSS/partialX"
```

currently, that is the only thing i can think of.

Comment: I tried it, as described in my post (without omitting the .. before the initial slash). Please see the newly edited post.

Comment: do ommit the ".."

Answer (score 0):

As formerly specified: "I am using/setting up Sass through Nebteans 8.1 "CSS Prepocessors" properties panel". Eventually I dug up the answer (terrible formatting and bizarre path names!) here:

https://groups.google.com/g/haml/c/WkB5lH20se8
(The chap took a lot of the sweat out of it, too.)

Finally several paths in Nebtbeans should be declared like so:

[image]

etc. Quite strange a syntax, is it not?